# Adding blank spaces to layout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make empty lines within android.  This is what I have been doing:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="\n\n"
```

I want to know if there is a better way?  Thanks

Comment: Padding? Margins? It would help to see the whole layout as it is an issue specific to individual layouts.

Answer (score 182):

Use `Space` or `View` to add a specific amount of space. For 30 vertical density pixels:

```
<Space
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

If you need a flexible space-filler, use `View` between items in a `LinearLayout`:

```
<View
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

or

```
<View
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

This works for most layouts for API 14 & later, except widgets (use `FrameLayout` instead).

[Updated 9/2014 to use Space. Hat tip to @Sean]

Comment: fill_parent is deprecated, so I updated to match_parent. Also, 0dip is recommended in many cases over match_parent.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this programmatically? Does it work the same as LinearLayout but replace LinearLayout with View?

Comment: Thanks, I used space as it is created for filling extra spaces

Comment: For backwards compatible spaces, use <android.support.v4.widget.Space

Answer (score 29):

If you don't need the gap to be exactly 2 lines high, you can add an empty view like this:

```
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">
    </View>
```

Comment: @wizurd Widgets can't use View, use FrameLayout in them instead of View.

Comment: This won't be _exactly two lines high_ as the line height depends on the text size, obviously.

Comment: Yep. That's what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 20):

**[View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)** if you need change background color , **[Space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html)** if not .

that dosent mean you have to change view background .

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/YOUR_BACKGROUND">
</View>
```

or Space

```
<Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
         />
```

Comment: Your hint in regards to when to use View and when to use Space solved my problem of not being able to show a background color. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!!! I was wondering about background color for space.

Answer (score 16):

An updated Answer: Since API 14, you can use "Space" View, [as described in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html).

> Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts.

Comment: An example for anyone wondering: `<Space android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="10dp" />`

Comment: Class Space extends View, and thus is heavier than a View

Answer (score 5):

if you want to give the space between layout .this is the way to use space. if you remove margin it will not appear.use of text inside space to appear is not a good approach.
hope that helps.

```
<Space
        android:layout_width="match_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2sp" />
```

Comment: It is very lightweight view, so we must use Space instead of View.

Answer (score 3):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#80000000">
</View>
```

Answer (score 3):

I strongly disagree with CaspNZ's approach.

First of all, this invisible view will be measured because it is "fill_parent". Android will try to calculate the right width of it. Instead, a small constant number (1dp) is recommended here.

Secondly, View should be replaced by a simpler class Space, a class dedicated to create empty spaces between UI component for fastest speed.

Answer (score 2):

try this

in layout.xml :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/empty_spaces" />
```

in strings.xml :

```
<string name="empty_spaces">\t\t</string>
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This can by be achieved by using **space** or **view**.

**Space** is lightweight but not much flexible.

**View** occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is responsible for drawing and event handling. View is more customizable, you can add background, draw shapes like space.

**Implementing Space :**

(Eg: Space For 20 vertical and 10 horizontal density pixels)

```
<Space
  android:layout_width="10dp"
  android:layout_height="20dp"/>
```

**Implementing View :**

(Eg: View For 20 vertical and 10 horizontal density pixels including a background color)

```
  <View
       android:layout_width="10dp"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:background="@color/bg_color"/>
```

Space for string formatting using HTML entity:

`&#160;` for non-breakable whitespace.
`&#032;` for regular space.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `weightSum` tag to `linearlayout` to 1 and for the corresponding view beneath it give `layout_weight` as .9 it will create a space between the views. You can experiment with the values to get appropriate value for you.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all the answers......also,

```
    <TextView android:text=""
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:layout_weight="2" />
```

should work :) I am just messing with others as TextView is my favourite (waste of memory though!)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers didn't work in my case. However, creating an empty item in the menu does.

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  ...
  <item />
  ...
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a better way to do this 
just use the code below and change according to what you want the size of the blank area

```
     <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="10" />
```

if you are using with the grid layoout then only use

```
 android:layout_row="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simple way to create blank line with line size.
Here we can adjust size of the blank line.
Try this one.

```
           <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="5dp"/>
```